# sich in etwas reinhängen

Tags: word-usage, usage

I've heard that some colleagues of mine are using verb **reinhängen**. After some googling and researching I have found following construct:

> sich in etwas reinhängen

It seems I do understand how I can use it in my daily speech and prepared some sentences myself.

However I would like to ask if these sentences make sense or they sound silly to native speakers:

> Sie hat sich total in die Vorbereitung der Geburtstagsparty
>   reingehängt
>
> Um diese Aufgabe zu erledigen, muss ich mich in die sorgfältige
>   Planung reinhängen

Comment: They are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Sie hat sich total in die Vorbereitung der Geburtstagsparty reingehängt.

Ok.

> Um diese Aufgabe zu erledigen, muss ich mich in die sorgfältige Planung reinhängen.

*Reinhängen* is strictly colloquial, so it doesn't match the stilted speech of the rest well. Better:

> Um die Arbeit zu erledigen, muss ich mich in die genaue Planung reinhängen.

Comment: Still, somehow "*in die genaue Planung reinhängen*" seems unnatural to me. You would say sloppily "*Mann, jetzt muss ich mich aber in die Planung reinhängen, damit da noch was draus wird*". Together with *genaue* however, the sentence bears a more reflective and controlled attitude where, for my understanding, *reinhängen* is not any more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally use "reinhängen" without the "in", and indeed without any object. The phrase tends to be a bit detached from the rest of the sentence:

> Anna hat die Party vorbereitet. Sie hat sich richtig reingehängt, und es ist super gelaufen.
>
> Um die Aufgabe zu erledigen, muss ich mich richtig reinhängen und sorgfältig planen.

Or:

> ... muss ich mich bei der Planung richtig reinhängen.

Your sentences are grammatically correct, but "sich reinhängen" is very colloquial, and the style of using nouns like "Vorbereitung" and sentences like "in die sorgfältige Planung" are more suitable for the style of a document or news report.